# How to list multiple doctor abbreviations?

Tags: abbreviations

I am pretty sure when listing multiple abbreviations for a doctor/dentist that it should be the following, using commas:

John Doe, DDS, MD, FACS

But I am have a client who insists it is:

John Doe, DDS. MD. FACS

I am unable to find anything official on this matter and hoping to do so. Thanks.

Comment: There is no single "official" way to display this information; it is a matter of style, and different style guides or editors may have different preferences. I would agree that commas are by far the most common format, but I'm not paying your bills.

Comment: It's a matter of style.  The name could also be listed (if not using the Aberdeen Style Guide) as "John Doe, D.D.S., M.D., F.A.C.S." in which case delimiting the degrees with periods would be confusing.

Answer (score 2):

As choster says, go with your client and pocket the money!

These days, the fashion seems to be to omit punctuation altogether.

> **2.17 Qualifications**
>
> Titles and qualifications should not carry full stops or spaces within them. Where qualifications appear after a
> name, they should be separated by a space but no comma.
>
> [University of Aberdeen - Style Guide](http://www.abdn.ac.uk/documents/style-guide.pdf)

Do a Google search for

***"style guide" qualifications***

You can narrow this down by country by appending **:UK** or **:US** for example.

Then you can choose whichever style suits. You can also send the link to your client as a way of persuading them.

Comment: I have no idea what your special characters are there, but Firefox displays them as a box with figures (character F0B7, which I suppose I *could* look up).

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Hi, I can't see any special characters. Where exactly  do they occur? I'll try to remove them.  P.S. maybe they're where I cut and pasted from a website? I'll edit to change my source.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/geHZk9a.png for what it looks like in Firefox

Comment: Yes, I see. I realise now that it happened because I cut and paste from a PDF document. I've changed it altogether now.

Comment: I can only say I am pleased I've never had to work with that farcical monstrosity of a style guide. So much inconsistency in so little space—and a style guide that almost goes out of its way to not even adhere to itself! \*shakes head*

Answer (score 0):

I found a good reference site and link to a very detailed page with what I was looking for.

http://doxical.com/blog/formattingpostnominalqualifications

http://doxical.com/style/int/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#href=Formatting-Postnominals.html&single=true